# Calling apex from Einstein Bot always transfers to agent

Tags: apex, einstein, bots

I am building a bot in my Sandbox and try to call an apex @Invocable method. I am able to set parameters for in and output. However, when invoking the action I am always getting transferred to an agent.

I have already added the apex class to the sfdc.chatbot.service.permset and assigned this to my profile.

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. Turned out that the variable I was passing was not set but required in apex...

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Bot Builder and select "Performance" in the top left then choose conversations and select a conversation where the class failed, it will usually show you the exception error that caused the class to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Please check and verify DATA Type of In vocable variables on your controller and  Action. I am also face this issue. On action of Dialog i create an custom entity type (Regex pattern) use as string and on controller i create in vocable string type.You use both variables as same data type it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, bot user need access to the incocable method. When I give permissions, all works